# How to work around declaring typedefs in C++ headers

Tags: c++, class, header, typedef

I wondered if anyone could offer suggestions, without restructuring, on ways to get around this situation: I have a header which contains a class declaration and declares a number of classes that it uses by reference / pointer which is clearly good practice compared to simply including the headers for those classes.

```
struct Foo;

struct Bar;

struct MyStruct
{
    void doIt( const Foo* foo );

    void doIt( const Bar* bar );
};
```

However, while in the example above Foo is a class, Bar is actually a typedef of a class as per the crude example below:

```
#include <fd_ex.h>

struct Foo
{
   int a;
};

struct Bar_
{
   int a;
};

typedef Bar_ Bar;
```

This causes some problems as predeclaring `struct Bar` is obviously not correct - `Bar` is not a struct:

```
"fd_ex.cpp", line 13: Error: Multiple declaration for Bar.
"fd_ex.cpp", line 19: Error: The name Bar is ambiguous, Bar and Bar.
2 Error(s) detected.
```

I don't want to expose `Bar_` if possible, mainly because in real life this could be very much more complicated than this example.

However, if I have **no control** over the struct declaration and typedef for `Bar`, are there any techniques I can use in the header for `MyStruct` to keep with the spirit of pre-declaring `Bar`?

Comment: I guess your compiler is just confused that you predefined bar as a class and later (via typedef) as a struct Bar_. Try to use struct bar; in your header file instead. Also before meaninglessly bashing the favor of others to use structs, please keep http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx this in mind ;-)

Comment: You're basically saying, "I want to declare a function, but I won't tell you what type the argument has." You can't do that.

Comment: @Najzero: They're actually all structs really, but it doesn't matter for this example as `Bar` is neither a class nor a struct. I'll change the example to make it clearer, but for the avoidance of doubt it still doesn't help.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What I want to know is how to tell the compiler what `Bar` is without confusing it by pre-declaring a struct that is actually not a struct but a typedef.

Comment: @Component10: You can't tell the compiler what `Bar` is if you refuse to tell the compiler what `Bar` is! The only right way is to declare `typedef struct Bar_ Bar;`, which is what `Bar` *is*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can forward declare the struct itself:

```
struct Bar_;

typedef Bar_ Bar; 

class MyClass
{
  void DoIt( Bar* );
};
```

Comment: Or even `typedef struct Bar_ Bar;` in one line... but I think the OP doesn't want anyone to say `Bar_` in the header!

Comment: @PaulManta: **if possible**, and there is a difference between exposing `Bar_` the structure definition and `Bar_` the symbol.

Comment: @PaulManta: What I said was "I don't want to expose Bar_ *if possible*" - The main reason being that some of the typedefs in the actual code I'm altering are pretty complex and I'd rather not repeat them verbatim if possible. This is mainly because (a) it adds extra maintenance overhead and (b) it *may* expose detail that I'd rather not in a header. That said, it does look to me like stijn / Kerrek SB's proposal is the (possibly only) way forward.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it works exactly the same in C++, but in C, I often declare "opaque" struct, which in header file (let's say `mystruct.h`) has:

```
typedef struct MyStruct_ MyStruct;

// + function prototypes using MyStruct*
```

and then I can use pointer to `MyStruct` without actually knowing what it is, like: `MyStruct *x;` , but not `MyStruct x[3];` (as the compiled does not know the size of MyStruct)

Then in the source file `mystruct.c` I define the `struct MyStruct_`.

So I think you could try to replace:

```
class Bar;
```

with:

```
typedef struct Bar_ Bar;
```

(you could probably just say `typedef Bar_ Bar;` in c++)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
struct Bar_;
typedef Bar_ Bar;
```